# Jsoup + java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://iv4u.health/

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to read URL body for domain - **iv4u.health** using Jsoup library (version 1.11.3) but getting "Too many redirects" error. Below is the code I am using -

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    crawlDomain("http://iv4u.health");
}

public static void crawlDomain(String url) {
    int timeout = 30;
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setRedirectsEnabled(false)
        .build();

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    CloseableHttpResponse response;
    try {
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        response = client.execute(request, context);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status >= HttpStatus.SC_MULTIPLE_CHOICES && status < HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST) {
            System.out.println(getURLBody(url));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getURLBody(final String url) {
    try {
        String userAgent = "Mozilla";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent(userAgent).get();
        return doc.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Below is the stacktrace of error -

```
java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://iv4u.health/
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.<init>(HttpConnection.java:717)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:751)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:773)
at ....
```

Please help me on this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The code works sometimes though(mostly first time)

Answer (score 1):

Try with url value with "http://iv4u.health". It works for me so please try it.

Comment: Hi, @Dhaval Goti, I have updated the code in the question. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something to do with the network setup. Have you tried browsing the same url in Mozilla or Chrome browser?

Below piece of code works fine for me (with `jsoup` 1.11.3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String url = "http://iv4u.health/";
        String userAgent = "Mozilla";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent(userAgent).get();
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Darshan, I have updated the code in the question. Please try now.